# Python: Is it more efficient to convert str to list before iteration?

Tags: python, string, performance, caching, data-structures

An example case has been asked, so I'll post a dummy code:

```py
example_str = ''.join([random.randint(9) for _ in range(9999)])

def iterate_string_v1(s):
    for char in s:
        print("Current char: %s" % char)

def iterate_string_v2(s):
    lst = list(s)
    for char in lst:
        print("Current char: %s" % char)


for _ in range(1000):
    iterate_string_v1()
    iterate_string_v2()  # <---- seeking details on why v2 excels in time
```

So I have been leetcoding for a while and I came across few people doing that, in order to improve performance. I've read that containers deliver objects themselves, and str iteration requires a copy of each char instead of delivering itself. I was wondering if this was true.

Also, assuming that above statement is true, then it makes no sense to convert if we are going to iterate string exactly once, right? For single iteration cases, list casting is same --or maybe even worse than-- as iterating the string and copying the chars. OTOH, for cases where we repeatedly iterate over the list --eg: subsequence search in string problems-- I think that's when list conversion excels.

Am I correct with these assumptions?
Are there any other basic performance improvement rationale regarding this "list vs str" approach? For example, do these two data structures perform the same on cache miss? Are the characters stored in same block in both str and list? I'm thinking: if either of them is list of pointers pointing to different blocks, then the iteration performance might be bad due to frequent cache misses.

Also I'd appreciate any data-structure related performance-improvement tricks just like this list-str phenomenon.

Comment: I think it would help if you provided actual examples of what you are talking about...

Comment: hi @Julien, sure, I've added a dummy code to elaborate.

Comment: Sorry your example doesn't make sense. Why do you believe `v2` is faster? It's definitely not for me. Create a [mre].

Comment: I also find the V2 code to be 40% **slower**, btw your example doesn't run you have a few things to fix.